# stop Chrome's click and hold / drag image default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I've noticed that in Google Chrome, one can click and hold an image and while holding a semi-transparent copy of that image attaches itself with the cursor. Then one can drag that image to the desktop to save it.

I want to prevent and stop the semi-transparent version of the image attaching itself to the cursor on hold of certain images in my site.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can prevent this behavior by using the property

```
-webkit-user-drag: auto | element | none;
```

See the doc of `-webkit-user-drag` [CSS-infos.net](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-drag) (I didn't find an MDN doc, if someone has a better reference)

---

### How to use

Add a `.nonDraggableImage` class on your `img` tags, and add on your CSS :

```
.nonDraggableImage{
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Comment: There is no IE equivalent to this property.

Comment: This is also useful to prevent links styled as buttons (Bootstrap a.btn) from being accidentally dragged by a clumsy user (me)

Comment: Does not seem to work on Firefox (using Mac Firefox 69)

Comment: @BenWheeler Indeed, it's a webkit property, not a standard (thus the mandatory -webkit prefix).

Answer (score 5):

I had to use a different solution to get it working:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" draggable="false">
```

Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7439078/2443005

Comment: Does not seem to work on Firefox (using Mac Firefox 69

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2020.  Works on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge and even Internet Explorer.  Funny how this is downvoted and the "-webkit-user-drag" answer .. which obviously will only work on webkit based browsers (lol) is upvoted.  Maybe it's just out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a transparent picture over the top of the picture you want to prevent viewing.

Please see: 
http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/stop-the-thieves-strategies-to-protect-your-images/

check under "Tricking the downloaders"

Comment: +1 Nice trick :) as it prevents basic user from right clicking and saving. But the "clean" way to prevent OP's behavior is still to use `-webkit-user-drag: none;`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use - draggable

> draggable="false"

```
<img draggable="false" src="image.jpg">
```

But you can try - ondragstart

> ondragstart="return false;"

```
<img ondragstart="return false;" src="image.jpg">
```

or - pointer-events (some browser don't support & also have other problems)

> style="pointer-events: none;"

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="pointer-events: none;">
```