# can anyone please give me simple answer (code) < something simple

Tags: php, html, css

i've learned at most everything i want it in the programing but I'm stuck with this little thing it's simple 
and that is how i can make the image unmoving when you click at the image

i mean ....

When you click on the image and hold on the image and move the cursor with the cursor the image will move with the cursor >>> now what i want is how i can make the image fixed and the image Not affected with the cursor ... did you understand me now ? ^^

please explain this simply and smoothly

thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable dragging an image from an HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211909/disable-dragging-an-image-from-an-html-page)

Comment: possible duplicate of [stop Chrome's click and hold / drag image default behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283017/stop-chromes-click-and-hold-drag-image-default-behavior)

Comment: You lost me after *"can anyone please give me simple answer (code)"*

Comment: "did you understand me now ? ^^"... eer no not really

Comment: please sir, can i have some more....code?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you dont deserve it ...

```
img {
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none;    
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;    
}
```