# setDragImage not removing ghost image on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I have an element that is draggable. I want to remove the ghost image, since I will be creating that in another way.

However, Google Chrome is not letting me stop the ghost image from appearing using [`setDragImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage). The blank image is being created before the drag, and I'm using `setDragImage()` inside the `dragstart` event handler, so I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The ghost image should not be appearing.

Here's an example:

```js
const blankCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

document.querySelector('.item')
  .addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(blankCanvas, 0, 0);
  });
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #fe0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="item">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/drhx7.png" alt="" class="item__img">
</div>
```

On Chrome, If you drag the box with the red border, the ghost image will appear, even though I'm using `setDragImage()`. Everything works correctly on Firefox (and Edge... doesn't even have the function).

My Chrome version is 66.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is coming from the image. If you try dragging the red border, it will work correctly. The problem will appear only when the drag begins on the image inside the draggable element. Maybe Chrome has some special treatment for images; I don't know.

You can mitigate this by disabling pointer events on the image:

```
.item img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const blankCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');

document.querySelector('.item')
  .addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(blankCanvas, 0, 0);
  });
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #fe0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
  /* The fix */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true" class="item">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/drhx7.png" alt="" class="item__img">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to remove the globe icon that gets added to the cursor on this example? I've seen some suggesting using `onmousedown="event.preventDefault()"` but that disables dragging altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "globe icon". Are you talking about the Not Allowed cursor? If so, I don't think there's any easy way to change it. I believe that the cursors used during drag and drop are based on the platform. For custom cursors, you would have to reimplement your own drag and drop using JavaScript.

Comment: That globe icon is very frustrating

Comment: @ness-EE If you're talking about the Not Allowed cursor, I think that means your mouse is not over a valid drop target. Maybe if you had a container that is a valid drop target surrounding the image then the cursor wouldn't turn into Not Allowed immediately. But that's a little beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Nope... I'm talking about the globe icon --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771196/stopping-chrome-from-changing-cursor-to-a-globe-while-dragging-a-link

Comment: @ness-EE I saw that question, but I'm still not sure what the globe is. I'm using Chrome, but all I see is a Not Allowed cursor. Can you take a screenshot or link to a picture of it?

Comment: @ness-EE I had the same globe icon problem (mac + chrome). Solution is canvas need to be part of the DOM. If we extend the example above before this line `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(blankCanvas, 0, 0);` you will want something like this: `document.body.appendChild(blankCanvas);`. This should remove the "404" globe default icon. (Of course you can remove the blankCanvas element on dragend event.

Comment: ^ was looking so long for this

Answer (score 3):

Adding to a solution provided by @ness-EE.

This is the solution I used and also handles case of hiding the globe in chrome

```
public handleDragStart( event : DragEvent ) : void {
    const blankCanvas: any = document.createElement('canvas');
    event.dataTransfer?.setDragImage( blankCanvas, 0, 0);
    document.body?.appendChild( blankCanvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with, `event.preventDefault()`, by using this ghost image will not be visible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).